# Is there a better conditional setTimeout pattern?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
if (isFlyoutAnimationDisabled) {
  flyOut();
} else {
  setTimeout(flyOut, 250);
}
```

It seems like there should be a better pattern than calling flyOut in each `if`  condition.  Seems wasteful to me and pollutes the code.

Is there a better way?

Comment: how many conditions are there?

Comment: isFlyoutAnimationDisabled?flyOut():setTimeout(flyOut, 250);

Comment: If a kid can read your 5 lines I think the code is perfect. Not knowing the surrounding context (without seeing more *polluting* code)

Comment: Does `flyOut` have to be called synchronously or would you accept `setTimeout(flyOut, isFlyoutAnimationDisabled ? 250 : 0)` ?

Comment: @RayToal It doesn't have to be called synchronously.  Other than that, is there a functional difference at all?

Comment: By synchronously I mean that flyOut is called right at the point your `if` statement appears. If you do `setTimeout(flyOut, isFlyoutAnimationDisabled ? 250 : 0)` thing, which is asynchronous, then flyOut is called _after_ the code in which it appears runs to completion.

Comment: Honestly.. Your code is better than all the answers. You are making a fork between synchronous and asynchronous code here and this is the pattern to do it. Totally agreed with @Roko C. Buljan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [if else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

```
if (isFlyoutAnimationDisabled) {
  flyOut();
} else {
  setTimeout(flyOut, 250);
}
```

Using [Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?:`

```
setTimeout(flyOut, isFlyoutAnimationDisabled ? 0 : 250);
```

by using the above consider that `setTimeout(fn, 0)` will perform as a *"nextTick"* giving this seemingly unexpected result

```js
const fn = () => console.log("A");

setTimeout(fn, 0) // "A"
console.log("B"); // "B"

// Logs:
// >> B
// >> A
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use promises, conditionals are simple:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

async function example() {
    if (!isFlyoutAnimationDisabled)
        await delay(250);
    flyOut();
}
// or without async/await:
function example() {
    return (isFlyoutAnimationDisabled
      ? Promise.resolve()
      : delay(250)
    ).then(flyOut);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary operator, for example:

```
isFlyoutAnimationDisabled ? flyOut() : setTimeout(flyOut, 250);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything, as the suggestion of using a ternary operator has already been put forward by one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
async function foo() {
  const delay = isFlyoutAnimationDisabled ? 0 : 250;
  await new Promise(x => setTimeout(x, delay));
  flyOut();
}
```

Literally no `if-else` needed. `Promise` is used here, and `concurrency` issue is avoided. Inspired by @Bergi's answer.